# Is there a way to end this python script by it self after five seconds of running?

Tags: python, led

Hi I'm trying to write a python script. I'm totally new to this.
What I'm wondering is if there is any way to make the script end by itself after running for five seconds? Happy if anybody knows? Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Display a runtext with double-buffering.
from samplebase import SampleBase
from rgbmatrix import graphics 
import time
import sys


class RunText(SampleBase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RunText, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.parser.add_argument("-t", "--text", help="The text to scroll on the RGB LED panel", default="hello")
        time.sleep(4)
        
    def run(self):
        offscreen_canvas = self.matrix.CreateFrameCanvas()
        font = graphics.Font()
        font.LoadFont("../../../fonts/5.bdf")
        textColor = graphics.Color(255, 255, 0)
        pos = offscreen_canvas.width
        my_text = self.args.text
    

        while True:
            offscreen_canvas.Clear()
            len = graphics.DrawText(offscreen_canvas, font, 0, 13, textColor, my_text,)
            offscreen_canvas = self.matrix.SwapOnVSync(offscreen_canvas)
            
            
# Main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_text = RunText()
    if (not run_text.process()):
        run_text.print_help()
```

Answer (score 0):

so it is pretty much like this:

```
import time, sys

time.sleep(5)
sys.exit()
```

or this:

```
import time

time.sleep(5)
exit()
```

or this option if running other processes in parallel:

```
import time, _thread, os


def stop(seconds):
    time.sleep(seconds)
    print('finished')
    os._exit(0)


_thread.start_new_thread(stop, (5,))

while True:
    print('running')
    time.sleep(1)
```

though I am not sure if such `os._exit()` is good or if it supported on all os

Comment: This does not answer OP's question. The idea is not to introduce a new 5-second waiting period in which nothing is done, and then exit; the idea is to forcibly terminate *already running code* if it takes too long.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I understand and am working on such a thing now

Comment: There is already a linked duplicate, so I would not bother.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel well, I already did so...

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully I will figure it out. But this helped.